# Interface object to covergroup

Tags: system-verilog

I want to tie my covergroup to the interface object. That`s why as a input to covergroup I specify the interface object:

```
interface fifoPorts #(parameter DSIZE = 8);
...
endinterface

covergroup write_cvr (fifoPorts itf) @(posedge itf.wclk);
coverpoint itf.winc iff (!itf.wrst_n);
coverpoint itf.wrst_n {
        bins actv =(1=>0);}
endgroup
```

However the simulator doesnt accept this, it raises an error in covergroup, saying that dentifier ('fifoPorts') found where a type or type identifier is required.
My question is: can covergroup accept interface object? And if yes, than whats wrong with my case?

Thanks
Hayk

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your covergroup header to use a virtual interface variable:

```
covergroup write_cvr (virtual fifoPorts itf) @(posedge itf.wclk);
```

and then pass an instance of fifoports to the constructor of the covergroup.